# Ошибка err_too_many_redirects при добавлении слэша через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Добавил в htaccess следующий код чтобы добавлялся слэш в конце адреса:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
   RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

При переходе по адресу /contacts получаю ошибку "Обнаружено слишком много переадресаций. (err_too_many_redirects)". Брал разные коды, которые у всех работали, у меня - нет. С чем может конфликтовать? У меня стоит только редирект с www на без www и на "дружественные" URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Неэкранированный слэш в регулярном выражении?

Comment: Точно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Неэкранированный слэш в регулярном выражении.